# How to insert more rows into a table

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I need to insert many rows into a table. The table has 9 columns, and for each row the values are the same, except for one column (docunumber). I could perform the same query whenever it is necessary limiting myself to change only the specified column. For example:

```
insert into dpa_note (testo, DATACREAZIONE, IDUTENTECREATORE, IDRUOLOCREATORE, TIPOVISIBILITA, TIPOOGGETTOASSOCIATO, 
    IDOGGETTOASSOCIATO,IDPEOPLEDELEGATO, IDRFASSOCIATO)
    values ('Documento validato con Verapdf', 3575, 252, 'T', 'D',--here docnumber one at a time--
    , NULL, NULL)
```

But is there a way to pass all docnumbers together and perform the insert with only one statement?

Comment: The possibilities depend on the database management system you're using. Please specify what DBMS you're using.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO dpa_note (testo, DATACREAZIONE, IDUTENTECREATORE, IDRUOLOCREATORE,
    TIPOVISIBILITA, TIPOOGGETTOASSOCIATO, IDOGGETTOASSOCIATO, IDPEOPLEDELEGATO,
    IDRFASSOCIATO)
SELECT 'Documento validato con Verapdf', 3575, 252, 'T', 'D', TIPOOGGETTOASSOCIATO,
       NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

It isn't clear from your question which column you want to use from the existing table.  I assumed it is `TIPOOGGETTOASSOCIATO`.